# Strange behavior on lambda and Dict.items()

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I'm trying to replace duplicate words from string with the code bellow:

```py
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

import re


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = 'User Key Account Department Account Start Date'

    result = reduce(
        lambda sentence, word: re.sub(rf'{word}\s*', '', sentence, count=1),
        filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] > 1 else '',
               Counter(sentence.split()).items()),
        sentence
    )

    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

    print(result)
    # User Key Department Account Start Date
```

But it does not print the expected. The strange part is in `filter`. If I list only results filtered:

```
[el for el in filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] > 1 else '', Counter(sentence.split()).items())]
# [('Account', 2)]
```

Despite what is specified in lambda, `x[0]`.

If I pass a not false value to else clause:

```py
[el for el in filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] > 1 else ['foo'], Counter(sentence.split()).items())]
# [('User', 1), ('Key', 1), ('Account', 2), ('Department', 1), ('Start', 1), ('Date', 1)]
```

What I'm missing here?

I'd like to do the following:

```py
[el for el in filter(lambda key,value: key if value > 1 else '', Counter(sentence.split()).items())]
```

And get `Account`. But it raises `*** TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

It works fine using list comprehension:

```py
[key for key, value in Counter(sentence.split()).items() if value > 1]
# ['Account']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. But I will explain what's actually happening.

Consider the expression `filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] > 1 else '', Counter(sentence.split()).items())`.

The first argument to `filter` is a predicate. This is a function which takes one input (`x`) and returns a value which is interpreted as a Boolean.

In this case, let's consider the predicate `lambda x : x[0] if x[1] > 1 else ''` - we will write this as `P` for shorthand. We will assume we call this function on an ordered pair `(a, b)` such that `a` is a string and `b` is a number.

Then we see that `P((a, b)) = a if b > 1 else ''`.

So if `b > 1`, then `P((a, b))` evaluates to `a`. This value is then interpreted as a Boolean (even though it's a string) because `P` serves as a predicate.

When we interpret some "container" data-type like a String as a Boolean, we interpret the container to be "true-like" if it is non-empty and "false-like" if it is empty. So in this case, `a` will be interpreted as `True` when `a` is non-empty and `False` when `a` is empty.

On the other hand, when `b <= 1`, `P((a, b))` will evaluate to `''` which is then interpreted as `False` (because it's the empty string).

So `P((a, b))` is a string which, when interpreted as a Boolean, is equal to `b > 1 and (a is non-empty)`.

So when we call `filter(P, seq)`, where `seq` is a sequence of pairs `(a, b)`, `a` a string and `b` a number, we see that we will keep exactly those pairs `(a, b)` where `b > 1` and `a` is non-empty.

This is indeed what happens.

However, it seems that what you want to happen is to only keep the items which occur more than once while ignoring their count. To do this, you need a combination of `map` and `filter`. You would want

```py
map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] > 1, Counter(sentence.split()).items()))
```

This first keeps only the pairs `(a, b)` where `b > 1`. It then takes each remaining pair `(a, b)` and keeps only the `a`.

Comment: @Kfcaio You're welcome! It's amazing how Python's "helpful" feature of automatically converting things to Booleans can actually make things really confusing. That's why I personally prefer statically typed languages - it's much harder to make mistakes like these because the type checker will tell you immediately what's wrong.